# How to check text in an input field

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am newbie to Selenium, and been having trouble verifying the text saved in a field.

This is the html for one of the rows.

```
<tr id="tier_no_1">
    <td class="ui-styled-table-odd-row"></td>
    <td class="ui-styled-table-odd-row"></td>
    <input id="tier_name" class="tierName required" type="text" name="tier_name"></input>
</tr>
```

I need to verify the text that is saved/entered into the field.
Normally I would use the following, but this just returns a value of 'null'

```
Assert.assertEquals("Tier 1", findElement(By.cssSelector("#tier_no_1 > td.ui-styled-table-odd-row > #tier_name")).getAttribute("tier_name"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `getAttribute("value")` to get the content of an `input`. Make sure the locator is correct.

```
Assert.assertEquals("Tier 1", driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#tier_name")).getAttribute("value"));
```

By the way, `id` should be unique in HTML, so you just need `By.cssSelector("#tier_name")`.

Comment: Thank you.That works perfectly.
I had being using 'tier_name' instead of 'value